# Get products where multiselect value is false

Tags: magento2, attributes, multiselect-attribute

how can I get products where the value of a multiselect is not set ?

I've got these so far :

```
$filter =
    array(
      array('eq' => array("378")), //multiselect with one value
      array('eq' => array("378,379")), //multiselect with 2 values
      array('eq' => false), //multiselect with no value, need to make this work
);

$collection->addAttributeToFilter( "multiselect", $filter );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$filter =
    array(
      array('eq' => array("378")), // multiselect with one value
      array('eq' => array("378,379")), // multiselect with 2 values
      array('null' => true), // multiselect with no value (null value)
);

$collection->addAttributeToFilter( "multiselect", $filter );
```

**Update:**

here is how it will work using the `SearchCriteria` with the product repository (tested on the custom attribute `available_shipping_methods` having a multiselect input type):

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

/**
 * Class Search
 */
class Search extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;

    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    private $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var FilterGroupBuilder
     */
    private $filterGroupBuilder;

    /**
     * Search constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory
     * @param FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productRepository            = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory = $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
        $this->filterBuilder                = $filterBuilder;
        $this->filterGroupBuilder           = $filterGroupBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $searchCriteriaBuilder = $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory->create();

            $filters = [
                $this->filterBuilder->setField('available_shipping_methods')
                                    ->setValue('%shipping_shipping%')
                                    ->setConditionType('like')
                                    ->create(),
                $this->filterBuilder->setField('available_shipping_methods')
                                    ->setValue('%flatrate_flatrate%')
                                    ->setConditionType('like')
                                    ->create(),
                $this->filterBuilder->setField('available_shipping_methods')
                                    ->setValue(null)
                                    ->setConditionType('null')
                                    ->create()
            ];

            $filterGroup = $this->filterGroupBuilder->setFilters($filters)
                                                    ->create();

            $searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup]);
            $searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

            $productList = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        }

        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create($this->resultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Result query looks like this (our conditions at the last line):

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`, IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) AS `visibility`, IF(at_available_shipping_methods.value_id > 0, at_available_shipping_methods.value, at_available_shipping_methods_default.value) AS `available_shipping_methods`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility_default` ON (`at_visibility_default`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id` = '99') AND `at_visibility_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '99') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_available_shipping_methods_default` ON (`at_available_shipping_methods_default`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_available_shipping_methods_default`.`attribute_id` = '265') AND `at_available_shipping_methods_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_available_shipping_methods` ON (`at_available_shipping_methods`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_available_shipping_methods`.`attribute_id` = '265') AND (`at_available_shipping_methods`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id WHERE (((IF(at_available_shipping_methods.value_id > 0, at_available_shipping_methods.value, at_available_shipping_methods_default.value) LIKE '%shipping_shipping%') OR (IF(at_available_shipping_methods.value_id > 0, at_available_shipping_methods.value, at_available_shipping_methods_default.value) LIKE '%flatrate_flatrate%') OR (IF(at_available_shipping_methods.value_id > 0, at_available_shipping_methods.value, at_available_shipping_methods_default.value) IS NULL))) AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1)
```

and result itself contains products with desired attribute value and without value at all (`null`).

**PS:** a comma-separated value of the multiselect attribute is the main problem, because of that we need to use `%LIKE%` condition, what is not a good idea.

Comment: Ok I'll try, but I think I'll just add the two options for each of my concerned products (like 2 options == 0 options)